# Combine line for line in two separate StringCollections

Tags: c#, wpf, stringcollection

I am attempting to take two string collections and combine each line in both collections simultaneously to show a full file path for my user.

Examples to help clear up confusion:

- String Collection 1 will contain a list of paths.
  Example:

  ```
  C:\windows\xxxx\xxx\xx, C:\Users\xxx\xxx, C:\test\xxx\xxx
  ```
- String Collection 2 will contain a list of file names.
  Example:

  ```
  file.txt, asd.txt, mydll.dll
  ```

Each list holds the key to one another in the same line number and I just need to combine them to output them to the end user.

```
String Collection Line 1 + SC2 Line 1 = Path
SC Line 2 + SC2 Line 2 = Path
SC Line 3 + SC2 Line 3 = Path
```

The information is not accessible in a combined state so I will be placing the data into two separate WPF TextBoxes and then their content will be pulled into a stringcollection.

First Collection

```
StringCollection lines = new StringCollection();
int lineCount = filePath.LineCount;

for (int line = 0; line < lineCount; line++)
    // Get line text and add to string collection
    lines.Add(filePath.GetLineText(line));
```

Second Collection

```
StringCollection lines2 = new StringCollection();
int lineCount2 = fileName.LineCount;

for (int line = 0; line < lineCount; line++)
    // Get line text and add to string collection
    lines.Add(fileName.GetLineText(line));
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

**Edit 1**

I have experimented with the ZIP command thanks to Eve but I also found an alternate route. Is there a safer route using zip compared to the code below?

Keep in mind I will have a function to check the line counts and make sure they are the same.

```
        StringCollection lines = new StringCollection();
        int lineCount = itemIDBox.LineCount;

        for (int line = 0; line < lineCount; line++)
        {
            string id;
            string rev;
            string combined;

            id = itemIDBox.GetLineText(line);
            rev = revBox.GetLineText(line);

            combined = id + @"\" + rev;

            lines.Add(combined);
        }
```

Comment: Instead of Concatenating the string using `+` why not look up the string.Join() method if not then look up the string.Split() method you want the paths you could just do `string[] splitStr = Split(',');`

Comment: Don't do `@"\"`, but instead use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Zip` method from `System.Linq`.

```
var fullPaths = lines.Cast<string>().
    Zip(lines2.Cast<string>(), (path, fileName) => Path.Combine(path, fileName)).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781134.aspx) instead of `+`.